# raise 404 instead of 500 in urls.py django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a website powered by django. There are few url patterns which i donot catch 
say `www.mysite.com/12233445`  `www.mysite.com/@##$$$`  `www.mysite.com/alphabetagamma` this leads to 500 error page, i want all such non-standard urls to redirect to 404 error page. Any clue which is the best method of doing it?

Comment: Normally if URLs don't match you would get a 404 page. You must have a URL that matches - please post your urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your views, perform all the get/filter operations within a try except  block.

```
try:

variable = object.get(some checks here)

except: object.DoesNotExist
 raise Http404

return (whatever)
```

Comment: Usually if the URLs is totally incorrect you should not hit the view at all. Example - if there is nothing at example.com/nothing it should raise 404 directly. The example above should be used if you are checking part of the url. Example example.com/news/news-exist is working (you view tries to find "news-exist" in the DB) example.com/news/news-does-not-exist should raise 404 after the news is not found in the DB. This is why you have get_object_or_404 method

Answer (score 1):

By using custom **handler500¶** you can change the response status code from 500 to 404. make your project to return this post may help you get the idea how to do it - http://ilian.i-n-i.org/custom-404-not-found-page-with-django-cms/

But as @Daniel said it isn't normal to get 500 for not found pages. Turn on the debug mode and check what error leads to 500.

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a `404.html` template? This happens when you have `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py`, yet you haven't created a `404.html` template. This raises a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception, hence the error 500 response.